# Meteor templates: If statement is no reactive

Tags: meteor-blaze

I'm having troubles with Blaze (Meteor 1.2.0.2)

***If* are evaluated in templates, but when their are not true anymore, the content is still printed.**

```
Template.registerHelper("equals", function (a, b) {
    return (a == b);
});

Template.login.helpers({
   'loadingLogoStatus': function(){
       lg(Session.get('logoDownloadStatus'));
       return Session.get('logoDownloadStatus');
   },
   'logoURI': function(){
       return Session.get(Session.get('logoURI')) || '';
   }
});
```

```
{{#if loadingLogoStatus equals 'WAIT_DOWNLOAD'}}
    Logo is loading...
{{/if}}
{{#if loadingLogoStatus equals 'ERR_DOWNLOAD'}}
    Logo loading error 
{{/if}}
```

The issue is in fact that as long as loadingLogoStatus == 'WAIT_DOWNLOAD', **Logo is loading...** is printed.

However when loadingLogoStatus = 'ERR_DOWNLOADED**, the previous string **remains there** and it's followed by **Logo loading error**.

Same situation if I try with a if/else construct.

I checked whether it was helper's issue and it wasn't since on Session variable change, the new value is printed to log.

Answer (score 1):

Try a === b

You need 3 equal signs In JavaScript to evaluate one value to another.

Comment: what's the exact difference when dealing with strings?

Comment: JavaScript uses this as it's comparison whether string , value, object, array etc. Try it. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

I found what the issue was.

I was using **equals** in the wrong position.

Right one:

```
{{#if equals loadingLogoStatus 'WAIT_DOWNLOAD'}}
    Logo is loading...
{{/if}}
{{#if equals loadingLogoStatus 'ERR_DOWNLOAD'}}
    Logo loading error 
{{/if}}
```